# Why can I not force a PyQt tabbed widget to resize?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QDialog containing a QTabWidget, whose tabs vary in size. Following [these instructions](http://colinoflynn.com/2012/11/qtabwidget-in-pyside-automatically-resize/), which are similar to another [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710003/force-qt-pyqt-pyside-qtabwidget-to-resize-to-active-tab), I have the following code (self.tabs is a dictionary of the tab widgets):

```
class Panel(NXDialog):

    def __init__(self, panel, parent=None):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabwidget.currentChanged.connect(self.update)
        ...

    @property
    def tab(self):
        return self.tabwidget.currentWidget()

    def update(self):
        if self.tabwidget.count() == 0:
            self.setVisible(False)
        else:
            for tab in [tab for tab in self.tabs if tab is not self.tab]:
                try:
                    self.tabs[tab].setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, 
                                                 QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
                    self.tabs[tab].update()
                except Exception:
                    pass
            self.tab.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
            self.tab.update()
        self.adjustSize()
```

When I add a new tab, this works very well. The tab does resize as I want. However, subsequent changes in the tab selection have no effect, even though my debugger confirms that this update function is called.

My application has an embedded shell that shares a namespace with the GUI so I can address all the PyQt widgets. If I call `tab.adjustSize()` in the shell,  where tab points to the selected tab, the tab does resize! So my question is why the `adjustSize` function is ignored when I make the selection and trigger the `currentChanged` signal using the GUI, but is not ignored when I call the same slot function a little later from a shell. I've tried adding a sleep time and recursively cycling through the parent widgets calling `adjustSize` for each of them, but it has no effect. I've also tried adding `self.repaint()` as well as programmatically changing focus and back again, but nothing works except typing it from the shell.

I'm running PyQt5 v5.12.5 on Python 3.8 but I get the same behavior with PyQt v5.9.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I really don't think that would be helpful here, since my application is extremely large with many interconnected parts. This is not a bug report. I am hoping that someone in the community can make suggestions of things to try based on their experience with similar issues.

Comment: Here we need an MRE, if your application is very large then it is not an MRE so you will have to make an effort to create a new project focused only on functionality, and then that will be the MRE. Those are the SO rules. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I have read thousands of SO questions that have not provided an MRE and yet have received multiple helpful comments. In fact, I have just come across another SO page that I think solves the issue, but also has no MRE. I will post shortly.

Comment: If the answer already exists then don't post the same answer, also remember that the SO rules have changed.

Comment: I have posted the answer because it did not show up when I looked before so the context is obviously different enough. Frankly, I thought that stackoverflow was encouraging a slightly more welcoming response to questions than I have received here (see https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214585/discussion-between-ray-osborn-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 0):

Another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949210/adjust-size-after-child-widget-resized-in-qt) has helped me solve the problem. It seems that the previous changes in `SizePolicy` might still have been waiting in the GUI event loop. Clearing the loop first ensures that the `adjustSize` works.

This is all that is needed.

```
        QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().processEvents()        
        self.adjustSize()
```

I confess I'm surprised this issue hasn't come up for me before, but I hope it's helpful to anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: Although I think this answer is still basically correct, it has triggered another PyQt5 bug, which causes the application to crash on exit if that widget is still open. I believe that it is the same bug described in the answer by @ekhumoro [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120337/why-does-pyqt-sometimes-crash-on-exit). I think it affects PyQt5 v5.12 and v5.13 but not v5.9.

Comment: In case anyone is allowed to read this in the future, the problem in the comment above was fixed following a suggestion on the PyQt mailing list (https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-May/042923.html). The trick is to explicitly close all top-level widgets before call the QApplication quit method. Deleting the QApplication instance itself does not appear to be necessary.